# Cucumber NoMethodError When Running Second Scenario in a Feature

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I have a simple Cucumber feature with two scenarios.  It uses watir-webdriver to perform basic log in and log out.  The first scenario (log in) runs fine, and the watir methods execute without problem.  When the second scenario is run (via running the feature as a whole), I get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method
>   `wait_until' for nil:NilClass

Playing around with this revealed that any calls to watir-webdriver methods in the second scenario throw this error, while the same methods are fine in the first scenario.  I assume I have a scope problem, and have tried "require 'watir-webdriver'" in my second scenario's step definitions to no avail.  I have included the step definitions for the two scenarios.  I've updated all my gems and have tried Cucumber 0.10.0 and 0.10.2 on Ruby 1.9.2.

Sorry; I'm quite new to ruby/cucumber/watir and have tried to sort this out for a few hours before posting.  Thanks very much for any advice!

```
require "watir-webdriver"

Given /^I have the proper credentials$/ do
  @username = "matt"
  @password = "abc123"
end
When /^I am on the login page$/ do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
  @browser.goto ("http://dev.example.net")
end
When /^I enter username and password$/ do
  @browser.text_field(:class, /x-form-field x-form-text/).set @username
  @browser.text_field(:index, 1).set @password
  sleep 1
  @browser.button(:text, 'Login').click
end
Then /^I should should be granted access$/ do
  @browser.wait_until { @browser.text.include? "Global Priorities" }
  fail unless @browser.text.include? 'Global Priorities' 
end

Given /^I am currently logged in$/ do
  @browser.wait_until { @browser.text.include? "Welcome: #{@username}" }
  fail unless @browser.text.include? "Welcome: #{@username}"
end
When /^I click the Log Out button$/ do
  @browser.button(:text, "Log Out").click
end
Then /^I should be logged out$/ do
  pending
end
```

Comment: I sorted this out by setting my env.rb file to launch the browser instance (common to all scenarios), and then removing the new browser instantiations from the steps themselves.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Matt, looks like you've got it figured out now.  Whenever you see an error regarding an undefined method for nil:NilClass - it means that whatever was trying to use that method no longer exists to do things with.

It may mean that you're using the wrong type of variable (instance/class/global) for your browser object, or that you've defined this browser someplace that is not being accessed during the second run through.